# Change Single Language of Xcode Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, itunes

How do you change the default language used by your project without doing localization?
What if I want my app to be in Japanese or Italian? Is it enough to just use Japanese or Italian texts? How do I change the language displayed on iTunes to say that it's in Japanese or Italian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the resources that you put in the main folder are assumed to be in the `Default language`, which is set in **iTunes Connect** when you add or edit the application.  The setting is on the `Application` page and if it's not correctly set after adding it, click the `Edit` at the top of the page to be able to change it with the drop-down menu.

If you're going to localize at all, you'll want to make sure to change the `localization native` language, you'll need to change the key in the `Info.plist` corresponding to `Localization native development region` (a.k.a. `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in raw form) to match the language you are using for the raw files.   The value of the tag should match the original localization language directory base (so `en` if you have an english lproj directory named `en.lproj`).   This language will be used in the event that one of the other localizations is missing for the specific resource.  Recommendations these days point to using the 2-letter version of the language (i.e. `en` instead of `English`, `jp` instead of `Japanese`, etc) as best-practice.

If you're building a Japanese-only app, you could just put all the resources in the top level.   If you're going to have Japanese and any other language, you should put the language-specific Japanese resources in `jp.lproj` and set the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to `jp`.   Any unlocalized resources (standard images, etc.) can be stored in the main application folder.

By the way, same general rules in OS X as well, except that wherever I mentioned "main application folder" above, the files would be within the **Resources** folder.

Comment: what if i have already submitted an app with en.lproj and it's now live on itunes. Then i realized that i want it to be jp.lproj only. can i just delete the en.lproj and replace it with jp.lproj for the next version of my app?

Comment: You should be able to do that as long as you also change the `Localization native development region` as noted above and make the change in the AppStore page.