# iOS default project language

Tags: ios, xcode

Quick question. I'm starting a new iOS project in Xcode. The default language (under Localization) is English, but my app is only going to support Portuguese. Should I delete the English entry and add Portuguese ou just leave as it is? Is it bad practice to leave English when my app won't be in English?

Notice that I'm not asking about localization - the app will only run in Portuguese. It's more about setting a default language.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534178/change-single-language-of-xcode-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't add any localisation at all.

The en-GB folder is only added if you add localisation.

Just write the app in Portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not going to support English anyhow than there is no need of keeping it, So it would be better if you delete it